# In google test, Is there an easy way to build a list of every test that results in a seg fault?

Tags: googletest

After a very large merge, a unit test project with a very large number of tests is seg faulting.  This is almost assuredly a problem with the code under test, and not google test itself.  After some experimentation, it's clear that it's not a single test at fault, but whatever the failure condition is, many tests trigger it.

Is there a good way to build a list of these tests?

The first thought was to write a python script that will iteratively run the test suite, detect a seg fault, find the last unit test being run, log it, and then rerun the test suite with that test excluded.  The problem is given the number of tests I suspect are crashing, and the time it takes to run the full suite, this would take many hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all tests by running your test program with `--gtest_list_tests`:

```bash
$ ./run_all_tests --gtest_list_tests
Foo.
  foo
  bar
  baz
...
```

You can then create a script that runs all tests separately by using `--gtest_filter`:

```bash
$ ./run_all_tests --gtest_filter='Foo.*' # Run all tests in a suite
$ ./run_all_tests --gtest_filter='Foo.foo' # Run a single test
```